# Bypass #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1?

Tags: mysql

I want to insert into `alerts_data` only the 3 first columns. I know that the values must be the same number as columns, but if I remove the `future_conditions_views` the query will not work.
How can I just insert the first 3?

```
INSERT INTO alerts_data (alerts_data_hash, alerts_data_id, alerts_data_hash_id)
SELECT behaviour.hash, future_conditions_alert, , CONCAT(behaviour.hash, future_conditions_alert) AS alerts_data_hash_id, future_conditions_views
FROM behaviour, active, future_conditions
WHERE behaviour.hash = active.hash
AND behaviour.url = future_conditions_url
AND active.last_active >= NOW( ) - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE 
AND behaviour.timestamp >= NOW( ) - INTERVAL future_conditions.future_conditions_day DAY 
GROUP BY behaviour.hash, behaviour.url
HAVING COUNT( * ) >= future_conditions.future_conditions_views
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE alerts_data.alerts_data_hash_id = alerts_data.alerts_data_hash_id
```

Comment: `SELECT` only the values you need to `INSERT`.

Comment: *"but if I remove some of the select the query will not work"* -- how comes? Show the complete `SELECT` query.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a join query and it's not modified correctly. Please post full query.

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos can you share the query with the `future_conditions_views` column and the error you're getting from it please?

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos Are you wanting the two columns `behaviour.hash, future_conditions_alert, CONCAT(behaviour.hash, future_conditions_alert) AS alerts_data_hash_id` inserted into alerts_data with those conditions in the full query or literally everything to go into alerts_data?